# SSIS Variable Changing Time Component

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS Variable named "DestinationDirectory" that has the following Expression:

```
@[User::SourceDirectory] + "\\" + REPLACE(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,35)((DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET, 7) GETDATE() ),1,19),":","")
```

It returns for example:

```
C:\Finance Extract\2018-11-10 125913
```

I then have a heap of other variables such as the one below named "DestinationFileAdjustment" that work off "DestinationDirectory". It has the following expression:

```
@[User::DestinationDirectory] 
+ "\\Adjustment_"
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("dd" , GETDATE()), 2)
+ "_"
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()), 2)
+ "_"
+ (DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("yyyy" , GETDATE())
+ ".csv"
```

What is supposed to happen is a file be created within that directory. The problem I'm experiencing is each time @DestinationDirectory is referred to, it is returning a different time value (e.g.  C:\Finance Extract\2018-11-10 125914) and errors out because the directory does not exist.

Is there a way I can set that variable at run-time and it retain the same time value each and every time it is referred to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `GETDATE()` in your expression, I'm guessing that you're using the time that the package begins in the "DestinationDirectory"  variable? If so, using the `@[System::StartTime]` system variable for the expression in this variable (example below) will provide this time and be consistent throughout the execution of the package.

```
@[User::SourceDirectory] + "\\" + REPLACE(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,35)((DT_DBTIMESTAMPOFFSET, 7) @[System::StartTime]),1,19),":","")
```

Answer (score 1):

What I finished up doing to get around this was to have a Script Task and the following code within it:

```
Dts.Variables("User::DestinationDirectory").Value = Dts.Variables("User::SourceDirectory").Value.ToString + "\\" + Replace(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), ":", "")
```

That hard coded the value for the variable nicely.